# How to integrate the Paypal In my website

Tags: c#-4.0, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm create a web site using c# ASP.Net in that site i need to integrate Paypal SDK. I have fallow the some links, as per that links i created a Paypal Account and Sandbox accounts too. When i check the Sandbox test account it shows Username , Password and Signature and i create my Business Account in that it give all credentials like END Point,Client-ID,Secret Code.After that i have fallow the documents which is in **Rest APIs** Make your first call i have try **Get an access token** i fallow the sample code

```
           https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
          -H "Accept: application/json" \
          -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
          -u "EOJ2S-           
             Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp" \
           -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

when i run above link in address bar it give error like

```
   {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR"}
```

Of course i downloaded some sample project from **CodetProject** site 
        http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers

but it does not works for me...

Please guide me how to start to do a sample ...Please Help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually part of a known issue. I'd like you to create a ticket at PayPal.com/mts and send me the ticket number. We're trying to get some traction on the impact and getting tickets created and assigned will help out a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi PayPal_Patrick , thank you very much for your response.This reference number  130621-000013 is this is TIcketnumber. ?

Comment: Im having the same Issue, it was working last week, since yesterday im trying with no luck..

Comment: Have you submitted a tick, @Saad? This issue should be resolved though. New .NET and Python SDK's were put out on github. You should be able to use the new V1.3.2 of sdk-core-dotnet

Comment: Hi Patrick Still i'm getting same error while i run url. I downloaded new V1.3.2 of sdk-core-dotnet  and run the application but give response error  like :  " Exception in HttpConnection Execute: Invalid HTTP response The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the update didn't resolve the problem like it was originally believed. Your original ticket was closed but I'll open a new one. Cory is researching the issue still.

Comment: Referring to ticket 130624-000452? I'll take a look at it today for you.